# firefox onclick event

Tags: php, jquery

This onclick function:

```
VVi".$row['id'].".onclick = function() {
   alert('1');
   var ResultI = '".$row['id']."';
   location.href='visuals.php?ResultI=' + ResultI + '&pg=' + pgi + '&vid=false';
};
```

Cannot be called on firefox... I tried it on chrome and opera, and everything worked fine... So how can i call the function that everything would work fine on all browsers. I need similar method, because i dont want related codes to get effect... Thanks

Edit:

Firefox result:

```
<a class='menuLink' id='VVi19'>
<div id='IIi19' style='width: 230px;
height: 136px;
background: url(res/images/images.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;'></div>
</a>
</td>
<script type='text/javascript'>
VVi19.onclick = function() {
    alert('1');
var ResultI = '19';
location.href='visuals.php?ResultI=' + ResultI + '&pg=' + pgi + '&vid=false';
     };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated source instead of PHP?

Comment: Looks like PHP issue causing invalid jQuery code, changing the tags.

Comment: Rob W, i don't think it's needed.. The php code has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Why not show the end result? So we can see what PHP is really printing out. If you you don't know how to get the end result: View the page (not locally) in a browser, and get the source code from your browser. You can do this by usually right clicking anywhere on the page and choosing "view source code" or something along those line.

Comment: ok this is the result from chrome. For some reason the scripts are not shown, but they are still working in chrome and opera... I dont get it...

Comment: in the firefox result the scripts are shown, but they arent working... Do you want me to write them?

Comment: ok now i posted the result perfectly... Please anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function declared as a closure as you have done there is an assignment **statement** and as such must be terminated with a semi-colon `;`.

Some ECMAScript engines are more forgiving than others about this - try adding the semi-colon, like so:

```
     // ...
     location.href='visuals.php?ResultI=' + ResultI + '&pg=' + pgi + '&vid=false';
   };
//  ^ Add this teminator
```

**Edit** after inspecting the whole code it would seem that the problem is that your tag order is all messed up, and that is why it is not working. Amongst other things, a `<script>` element is not valid as a direct child of a `<table>`, and a `<td>` should be enclosed in a `<tr>`. You also assign a static `id=` in a loop, which result in duplicated element IDs, and you seem to be referencing HTML elements using an object named with their ID, without assigning the element to the object.

Try changing:

```
VVi".$row['id'].".onclick = function() {
```

To:

```
document.getElementById('VVi".$row['id']."').onclick = function() {
```

...although even if this does fix your immediate problem, you will likely find other stuff that doesn't work. You need to pass all you generated pages through the [W3C markup validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) and you should also see what [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) has to say about your Javascript.

Comment: still not working. Still thanks i din't knew anything about that :)

Comment: @Liukas I'm afraid we will have to see it in action - do you have a link you can provide so we can see the problem for ourselves?

Comment: Can anyone drop a ling where i can post you the whole code, please?

Comment: @Juhana It would appear that when I edited for spacing purposes I absent mindedly added it in. <facepalm>